# gtsummary::tbl_regression() - Obtain Random Effects from GLMM Zero-Inflated Model

Tags: gtsummary

When trying to create a table with the conditional random effects in [r](/questions/tagged/r) using the [gtsummary](/questions/tagged/gtsummary) function **tbl_regression** from a glmmTMB mixed effects negative-binomial zero-inflated model, I get duplicate random effects rows.

Example (using Mollie Brooks' Zero-Inflated GLMMs on Salamanders Dataset):

```
data(Salamanders)
head(Salamanders)

library(glmmTMB)
zinbm2 = glmmTMB(count~spp + mined +(1|site), zi=~spp + mined + (1|site), Salamanders, family=nbinom2)

zinbm2_table_cond <- tbl_regression(
    zinbm2, 
    tidy_fun = function(...) broom.mixed::tidy(..., component = "cond"),
    exponentiate = TRUE,
    estimate_fun = purrr::partial(style_ratio, digits = 3),
    pvalue_fun = purrr::partial(style_sigfig, digits = 3))

zinbm2_table_cond
```

Output:

[Random Effects Output (cond)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59yef.png)

When extracting the random effects from de zero-inflated part of the model I get the same problem.

Example:

```
zinbm2_table_zi <- tbl_regression(
   zinbm2, 
   tidy_fun = function(...) broom.mixed::tidy(..., component = "zi"),
   exponentiate = TRUE,
   estimate_fun = purrr::partial(style_ratio, digits = 3),
   pvalue_fun = purrr::partial(style_sigfig, digits = 3))

zinbm2_table_zi
```

Output:

[Random Effects Output (zi)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXaet.png)

The problem persists if I specify the effects argument in broom.mixed.

```
tidy_fun = function(...) broom.mixed::tidy(..., effects = "ran_pars", component = "cond"),
```

Looking at confidence intervals in both outputs it seems that somehow it is extracting random effects from both parts of the model and changing the estimate of the zero-inflated random effects (in 1st image; opposite in the 2nd image) to match the conditional part estimate while keeping the CI.

I am not knowledgeable enough to understand why this is happening. Since both rows have the same label I am having difficulty removing the wrong one.

Any tips on how to avoid this problem or a workaround to remove the undesired rows?

If you need more info, let me know.
Thank you in advance.

PS: Output images were changed to link due to insufficient reputation.

Comment: Can you please update your post with a _minimal_ reproducible example (aka a reprex)? Code+data we can run on our machines.

Comment: Hello @DanielD.Sjoberg . Updated the post using Mollie Brooks' Zero-Inflated GLMMs on Salamanders Dataset ([link](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/biorxiv/suppl/2017/05/01/132753.DC1/132753-2.pdf)), with a small tweak (added random effects to zi part. Tell me if you need any more info.

Comment: It looks like this is a bug in `broom.mixed::tidy.glmmTMB()`. You can subscribe to this GitHub Issue to be notified of updates about its resolution. https://github.com/bbolker/broom.mixed/issues/136

Comment: I will. Thank you very much for your time and dedication both to the package and the community.

Comment: Looks like it's been corrected in the dev version of broom.helpers!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Though I installed the dev version (I assumed that you meant `broom.mixed`), I am still having some problems. I posted these issues as a reply to the github post that you linked above. Thank you once again.

Comment: I see you posted on the GH Issue. I recommend that you update your post to include a minimal reproducible example illustrating the persistent bug.

Comment: Fixed on `packageVersion("broom.mixed") #‘0.2.9.4’`. Make sure to have `packageVersion("glmmTMB") #‘1.1.4’`.